# /var/www alter default directory and file permissions

Tags: permissions

I've set up my apache2 server along with vsftpd. A shortcut to the `/var/www` folder is in `/home/pi` and I've taken ownership of the folder using:

`sudo chown -R pi /var/www'

When files are uploaded via FTP they are set to permissions: 600

But when viewing this files via the web browser a 403 Forbidden is shown.
I can change the file permissions manually but images are uploaded from CCTV cameras 24/7.  How can I change this so that the permissions are set automatically?

Comment: The name you are looking for is "umask". What I don't know is whether vsftpd will respect the umask you set in your default one (check /home/pi/.profile and /etc/profile). Check "man umask" for help on the cryptic 4-digit number.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, publicly accessible services (such as nginx/apache or sftp) run as the **www-data** user.  When you changed the owner to **pi**, you most likely removed permissions for the sftp user.

You should return the permissions to that which they were (ls -lsa /srv/www will give you the actual user/group, as I am making an assumption here):

- `sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /srv/www`
- `sudo chmod g+rw -R /srv/www`
- `sudo chmod g+s -R /srv/www`
- `sudo usermod -a -G www-data pi`

Now, the files should be accessible to sftp/web and **pi** belongs to the www-data group, giving it permission to edit the files.

Be sure you're writing in umask 002 of 007.